# Regex question regarding single character

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I would like to use regex to replace a single character in a URL.

The url is below:

```
http://www.example.com/e343/Product.html
```

I would like to use regex to replace any character that is not a `"t"` after the first slash. In this case the letter being used is the letter `"e"`

In this case I am using ColdFusion MX so if there is an alternative to regex I'll be happy to use it.

Comment: Those are *forward* slashes, not backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

```
([^/]+//[^/]+/)([^t])


$1 = before your inalid character
$2 = the char 'e', ot anything other than 't'
```

Based on your parser you may need to escape */* chars to *\/*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REReplace function in CF MX for this. The basic idea to to make a regex that puts everything **except** the character you want to replace into capture groups, and use the backreferences to keep them in the replacement string.  Something like:

```
REReplace(url, "(^http://[^/]*/)([^t])(.*)", "\1t\3", "ONE")
```

If the first character after your first / is a t, the entire regex won't match, and nothing will get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfset address = 'http://www.domain.com/e343/Product.html' />
<cfset updated = reReplaceNoCase(address, '(\w/)[^t]?', '\1') />
<cfoutput>#updated#</cfoutput>
```

Result

```
http://www.domain.com/343/Product.html
```

It always finds the first slash preceded by a letter, and also includes the letter after the slash if it is not a 't'. Then it replaces the match with everything except for the letter that is not 't'.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the most useful regular expression page i have ever found. Every developer should link to this one.

http://txt2re.com/